# NIntegrate option for FourierSeries

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I would like to use `FourierSeries` but it is very slow. My guess is that it is because it uses symbolic integration:

```
(* function for the example *)
f[t_] = Cos[t] + 0.2*Sin[2*t] + Piecewise[{{.1, 1 < Mod[t, 2 Pi] < 2}}, 0];
(* using `FourierSeries` *)
FourierSeries[f[t], t, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* using `NIntegrate, manually *)
Total[Table[Exp[I*k*t]/(2 Pi)*NIntegrate[f[t]*Exp[-I*k*t],{t, -Pi, Pi}],
     {k, -3, 3}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> 10.129225 (* for `FourierSeries` *)
>
> 1.923198 (* with `NIntegrate` *)

I am sure there is an easy way to force `FourierSeries` to use `NIntegrate`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use *NFourierSeries*?

```
<< FourierSeries`
f[t_] = Cos[t] + 0.2*Sin[2*t] + Piecewise[{{.1, 1 < Mod[t, 2 Pi] < 2}}, 0];
NFourierSeries[f[t], t, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming
{3.39228, Null}
```

This time is measured on my laptop!

Comment: For a very simple reason: I did not know `NFourierSeries` existed. That's exactly what I was looking for. Computation time is very close to that of `NIntegrate` (tested for k from 3 to 20), but it's simpler. 

I did not find `NFourierSeries` from the documentation. I think it is because it requires the package `FourierSeries`. What would have been a good approach to possibly find it?

Comment: Look at the documentation "guide/StandardExtraPackages"

Comment: @anderstood With "NFourierSeries" you can get warning messages. Please insert then "AccuracyGoal".